# Verify the response code of the page with Capybara and Selenium

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm trying to verify the response code of a page by using capybara. I used the expect statement as -

```
    expect(page.status_code).to eq(404)
```

I'm getting the error as -

```
    Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
    Capybara::Driver::Base#status_code
```

Might be status_code is not supported by Capybara. Is there any other way to verify the status/response code or I'm doing something wrong in the expect statement.

Comment: actually it doesn't return any error for me. Yet it seems the test framework is not getting the right status_code : I have a redirect when user is not logged in (I have not implemented the sign-in process yet) and status_page is 200 instead of 302. It doesn't seem reliable to test when multiple status are returned....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Selenium driver doesn’t support status_code because it’s not really something you should be testing in a feature/system test. The idea of feature/system tests (which Capybara is aimed at) is to test from a users perspective. Since a user cares about what is shown in the browser thatts what should be tested for rather than the status code. If you still want to test for the status code it should be done in a request spec rather than a feature/system spec

Comment: Move this test to your controller tests, then check the response.content_type, response.status, response.headers, response.body.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need JavaScript you can try to fall back on the default rack_test driver:

```rb
it "responds with status code 404", js: false do
  expect(page.status_code).to eq(404)
end
```